# FabricJS line selection with perPixelTargetFind varies depending on angle of line

Tags: fabricjs

I'm using `perPixelTargetFind: true` in combination with `targetFindTolerance: 15` to allow users to select lines on canvas by clicking on the line as opposed to the full bounding box that is the default in Fabric.

This works great when a line is drawn at an angle as selecting is easy and the user doesn't have to be too specific with where they click. However, when the line is drawn either perfectly horizontally or vertically the line becomes almost impossible to select, almost like the targetFindTolerance value decreases to 0 depending on the angle of the line.

Here is a simplified [example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KQdapX?editors=1010).

You'll notice the cursor change when you are able to select a line, and after selecting the line will change to red.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about giving `padding:value` to object.

Here is updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/durga598/pen/LQpLZo)

Comment: So simple. Thanks very much!